# What is the best way to provide uninstall for macOS apps?

Tags: macos, uninstallation

I have a macOS app which is installed in `/Applications/MyApp.app`.

Application also puts some content in `~/Library/Preferences`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/.myappcontent/`.

If user just deletes `MyApp.app` from `/Applications` folder, then all the other stuff still remains. Even `AppCleaner.app` doesn't find all that stuff.

Is there some recommended way to uninstall the macOS apps? Like providing `uninstall.sh` somewhere or having some script executed when MyApp.app gets deleted?

Comment: Preferences should be no problem, keeping them may be useful when a user wants to reinstall the App. I would recommend to use `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/` instead of the non standard `~/.myappcontent`. Cleaning apps might have a chance to find the data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, my conclusion has been to put app's data in `~/Library/Application Support/<bundle-id>` folder.

That one will be picked up by `AppCleaner.app` or other utility apps used for cleaning/uninstalling software from macOS.

Also, content from `~/Library/Preferences` will also be picked up (ie plist form `StandardUserDefaults`.